# Rake Task environment variable w/Command Line Arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

So I was getting some "Uninitalized constants" on my rake task, and I did some googling and found that the environment variable needed to be loaded in. However im also using a command line argument and im not sure if the positioning is correct or what:

```
desc "Wipes Specific User"
task :clean_user => environment [:user] do |t, args|
  puts "Running clean_user for #{args[:user]}..."
  Core::Stuff.find(args[:user]).wipe_user
end
```

Without the environment variable somewhere I get complains about Core::Stuff being uninitialized, but Im trying to pass :user via CL. (This is just a sample rake task to make sure stuff works).

Am I missing something?

edit: Fixing the issue with:
`task :clean_user, [:user] => :environment` however now it seems to be loading my PATH into the argument (I get an error complaining how "Core::Stuff cannot find a user id with id of "" . So it's like it's using my CL path as the ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs in the gem specify:

> task task_name, arguments => dependencies

That means your code needs to be:

```
task :clean_user, [:user] => :environment do |t, args|
```

Comment: I think it may be :environment (it complains about it otherwise: "undefined local variable or method `environment'"), the weird thing is, is that it's loading my .find(args[:user]) with my CL path? Error: "Couldn't find Core::Stuff with 'id'=
/Users/me/Documents/Project/lib/tasks/clean_user.rake"    So it's like it's using my environment variable as an argument (Im running the rake task as rake clean_user <user id here>

Comment: Any idea why it's loading my path into the :user argument?

Comment: how are you invoking the rake task?

Comment: "Bundle exec rake <task_name> <param>